# How should I put a function to react native switch?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to ask if anyone know how to wire a function to the switch component in react-native?

I am currently building an app where on one of the page, there is a switch button. When user flip on or off, it will trigger some event on the same page.

Below is my current code for that specific page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { MapView } from 'expo';
import { Switch } from 'react-native-switch';


const window = Dimensions.get('window');

class TestScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = () => ({
        title: 'Test',
    });


    onButtonPressInfo = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('info');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <MapView 
                    style={styles.mapcontainer}
                    zoomEnabled
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: 3.1412000,
                        longitude: 101.6865300,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                    }}
                />
                <View style={styles.switchContainer}>
                    <Switch 
                        disabled={false}
                        backgroundActive={'green'}
                        backgroundInactive={'red'}
                        circleActiveColor={'#30a566'}
                        circleInactiveColor={'#000000'}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonBottomContainer}>
                    <Button
                        small
                        title="Info"
                        backgroundColor="#009688"
                        icon={{ name: 'search' }}
                        onPress={this.onButtonPressInfo}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>         
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    mapcontainer: {
        flex: 1,
        height: window.height,
        width: window.width
    },
    switchContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
        left: 20,
        right: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    buttonBottomContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20,
        right: 20
    }
};

export default TestScreen;
```

In the code above, the page will show a map, a button `info` and a switch. Current situation, when I click the `info` button, it will navigate me to a page I'd setup called `infoPage`.

I want when I flip the switch, and I click on `info`, it will changed the navigation to the other page for example `infoPage2`. While I understand about how to navigate between pages from button, but I did not really understand how should I implement the function to the switch so whenever I flip on or off, the `info` button will show/navigate me to either `infoPage` or `infoPage2`.

I already searched the documentation for switch [example1](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html),[example2](https://github.com/poberwong/react-native-switch-pro),[example3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-switch) but could not found any near enough example for what I want to achieve.

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to keep track of the state of switch, now when you press the info button you could check if switch is turned on or off and do your next step based on that. see code example below I added some comments

```
class TestScreen extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    infoSwitch: false // set the default state of switch to false
  };
  this.onSwitchValueChange = this.onSwitchValueChange.bind(this); // we need to bind this to a new function for handling state changes on switch component
  }
  static navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: 'Test',
  });
  onSwitchValueChange(value) {
    // change the tracked state to the current value
    this.setState({
      infoSwitch: value
    });
  }
onButtonPressInfo = () => {
    // you could now check if what is the state of switch in here

    if (this.state.infoSwitch === true) {
      // do something if switch is turned on
    } else {
      // do something if switch is turned off
    }


}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <MapView 
                style={styles.mapcontainer}
                zoomEnabled
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 3.1412000,
                    longitude: 101.6865300,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
            />
            <View style={styles.switchContainer}>
                <Switch
                    value={this.state.infoSwitch} // set the value into the tracked state
                    onValueChange={this.onSwitchValueChange} // give the function that would handle value change for this component
                    disabled={false}
                    backgroundActive={'green'}
                    backgroundInactive={'red'}
                    circleActiveColor={'#30a566'}
                    circleInactiveColor={'#000000'}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonBottomContainer}>
                <Button
                    small
                    title="Info"
                    backgroundColor="#009688"
                    icon={{ name: 'search' }}
                    onPress={this.onButtonPressInfo}
                />
            </View>`
        </View>         
    );
}
}
```

I hope this would help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this https://github.com/Recr0ns/react-native-material-switch and there is 3 function for event

```
<Switch 
    disabled={false}
    backgroundActive={'green'}
    backgroundInactive={'red'}
    circleActiveColor={'#30a566'}
    circleInactiveColor={'#000000'}
    onChangeState={(v) => someFunction}
    onDeactivate={(v) => someFunction}
    onActivate={(v) => someFunction}
/>
```

On this 3 function (onChangeState, onDeactivate, onActivate), you can write your own function.